# make menu and submenu angularjs from database mysql

Tags: php, angularjs

how to create menu and sub menu html from angular with database MySql.
i have table from mysql like this.

```html
id  menu
1   master
2   aplikasi
3   laporan
```

menu.php

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>

<ul>
   <li ><a href='#'><span>HOME</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Master</span></a>
   <ul>
   <li><a ui-sref="user" ui-sref-active="active"><span>User</span></a></li>
   <li><a ui-sref="produk" ui-sref-active="active"><span>Produk</span></a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Aplikasi</span></a>
   <ul>
   <li><a  ui-sref="transaksi" ui-sref-active="active"><span>Transaksi</span></a></li>
   <li><a ui-sref="stok" ui-sref-active="active"><span>Stok Barang</span></a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>laporan</span></a>
    <ul>
   <li><a ui-sref="itt" ui-sref-active="active"><span>Item terdisplay</span></a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>

 <!-- my app.js-->
var app = angular.module("app",['ui.router']); // jangan lupa kita inject module ui.router
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
 $stateProvider
   .state("itt",{ 
    url: "/itt", 
    templateUrl : "modul/itt/itt.php" 
   })
   .state("home",{
    url : "/home",
    templateUrl : "home.php" // path template
   })
   .state("user",{
    url: "/user",
    template : "<h1>Halaman User</h1>"
    //controller : "Menu3Ctrl"
   })
   .state("produk",{
    url: "/produk",
    template : "<h1>Halaman Produk</h1>"
    //controller : "Menu3Ctrl"
   })
   .state("transaksi",{
    url : "/transaksi", 
    template : "<h1>Halaman Transaksi</h1>"

   });  
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("home");
});
```

i want replace menu in menu.php with my menu in database

Comment: Is this really all you have? Post your code and the error you're running into.

Comment: updated... pls help me

Comment: so you want to query the database to generate the menu? where are you querying the database?